# Changes to the brain regions due to PTSD

Tags: neuroscience, cognitive-neuroscience, neurophysiology, fear, ptsd

I mentiond in my other question today ([Changes to the amygdala due to PTSD](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/28606/7604)) that the one thing I have often heard regarding changes in the brain due to trauma and PTSD is that the amygdala is enlarged (e.g. [Kuo, Kaloupek & Woodward, 2012](https://doi.org/10.1001/archgenpsychiatry.2012.73)). Looking more into changes in the brain due to PTSD, there are others that occur.

Bremner ([2006](https://doi.org/10.31887/DCNS.2006.8.4/jbremner)) reports that

> Findings from animal studies have been extended to patients with post-traumatic stress disorder (PTSD) showing smaller hippocampal and anterior cingulate volumes, increased amygdala function, and decreased medial prefrontal/anterior cingulate function.

Is hippocampal function reduced with the reduction in volume? I assume so.

Are there other known changes in the brain regions due to PTSD?

### References

Bremner J. D. (2006). Traumatic stress: effects on the brain. *Dialogues in Clinical Neuroscience 8*(4), 445-461. https://doi.org/10.31887/DCNS.2006.8.4/jbremner

Kuo, J. R., Kaloupek, D. G., & Woodward, S. H. (2012). Amygdala volume in combat-exposed veterans with and without posttraumatic stress disorder: a cross-sectional study. *Archives of general psychiatry, 69*(10), 1080-1086. https://doi.org/10.1001/archgenpsychiatry.2012.73